# Which Dua is know as Mustadafeen/Mustazafeen?

Tags: source-identification, dua

I've looked around to try to find some posts on this but none that address my specific question (that I could find). I want to know which Dua is known as **Mustadafeen** or **Mustazafeen** according to **Hadith** or **Quran**.

Jazak Allah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prophet Mohammad(PBUH) when returning from TAIF, people started foul mouthing towards him and started throwing rocks due to which Prophet (PBUH) got hurt and his sleepers were covered in blood, Hazrat Zaid tried to protect him and got injured himself. Prophet(PBUH) took refuge at a garden about three miles away from TAIF. While sitting in the garden and thinking about what had happened he(PBUH) made an emotionally painful prayer which is known as Dua MUSTAZAFEEN

"Allahumma Ilaika Ashku Suafa...................."

(PBUH)=Peace Be Upon Him

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Dua-e-Taif you may search on net.
I have posted it without translation. 
On net you can find translation.